# Effect Plot R - Putting data points into effect Plot

Tags: r, effects

current effect plot look in [image: R]

To all: I am trying to understand if there is a way to develop my effect plots further. I was wondering if there is a way to get the data points used to create the effect plots onto the effect plot itself, so it sort of looks like a scatter diagram.

I am using the packages: (ggplot2), (stargazer), (effects), (gridExtra), (plyr)

Code Used:

```
setwd("F:/Sussex PhD/data/constresult19")
my_gen <- read.csv("genhis.csv") #data set name

#linear models
const.qualsvc <- lm(Conpv1019 ~ + Noqual19 + Alevel19 + Degplus19 + Const5ac + Gdschlsrate + FSMKS2 + FSMAlevel, data = my_gen)
const.qualsvl <- lm(Conpv1019 ~ + Noqual19 + Alevel19 + Degplus19 + Const5ac + Gdschlsrate + FSMKS2 + FSMAlevel, data = my_gen)
stargazer(const.qualsvc, const.qualsvl, type = "text")

#effect plots
eddeg.cona <- effect(term = "Degplus19", mod = const.qualsvc)
eddeg.cona <- plot(eddeg.cona, ylim=c(-20,30), xlab = "Percent Degree Qualification Plus", ylab = "Percentage Change in Con vote 2010-19", main="Effect of Degrees on Change in Con % Vote", col.line = "blue")
eddeg.laba <- effect(term = "Degplus19", mod = const.qualsvl)
eddeg.laba <- plot(eddeg.laba, ylim=c(-20,35), xlab = "Percent Degree Qualification Plus", ylab = "Percentage Change in Lab vote 2010-19", main="Effect of Degrees on Change in Lab % Vote",col.line = "red")`

grid.arrange(eddeg.cona, eddeg.laba, ncol=2)`#effect plots side by side
```

Kind Regards, James Prentice (Only a fairly basic level user of R)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO. I've never used the `effects` package, but it looks like you can extract the elements used to plot the fit and confidence intervals from the object produced by `effect()`. Without seeing your data, I can't provide much more advice than this minimal reproducible example though. Let me know if you have any questions.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(effects)

mpg.model <- lm(data = mtcars, mpg ~ wt + cyl) 

wt.eff <- effect(term = "wt", mod = mpg.model)

mpg.model.plot.data <- data.frame(
  wt.eff$x,
  eff.lower = wt.eff$lower,
  eff.upper = wt.eff$upper,
  eff.fit = wt.eff$fit
)

ggplot(data=mpg.model.plot.data, aes(x = wt)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = eff.lower, ymax = eff.upper), fill = "blue", alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_line(aes(y = eff.fit), color = "blue")
```